# Por qué la aplicación funciona aunque no introduzca && primo en bucle for?

Tags: java, algoritmos

Esto es una aplicación para comprobar si el número que introduces por teclado es primo o no es primo. Lo que no entiendo es por qué me funciona la aplicación aunque dentro del bucle for no introduzca "&& primo".

Tal y como lo entiendo, si introduzco por teclado un 8 la última operación que el bucle comprueba es el resto de dividir 8/7 y por lo tanto en la última vuelta del bucle la variable "primo" tendría que continuar true.

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test_04 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean primo=true;
        Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introduzca un número por teclado:");
        int numero=reader.nextInt();

        for(int i=2;i<numero && primo;i++){  
            /*¿Por qué funciona aunque no introduzca && primo en el for?*/

            if(numero%i==0)primo=false;

        }
        if(primo){
            System.out.println(" primo ");
        }else{
            System.out.println(" no primo ");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Depuralo paso a paso para que veas que sucede, pero en la última vuelta que comentas 8/7 el residuo no es cero por eso pone false

Comment: si no le pones `&& primo` hace todo el bucle aunque `primo` sea false en la primera iteración ( 8 es divisible por 2 )

Comment: para verlo agregale un `System.out.println(numero + "\t" + i + "\t" + (numero%i==0) + "\t" + primo );` luego del `if(numero%i==0)primo=false;`

Comment: Aparte, conviene tener en cuenta para las pruebas casos especiales , como en este caso `0`, `1` y `2` (pista: ni el `0` ni el `1` son primos). Y no está de más comprobar los valores de entrada (¿qué pasa si el valor es negativo?) aunque eso más para código "de producción" que para ejercicios.

Comment: @aloMalbarez te da la respuesta más clara, sin el `&& primo` el bucle debe ejecutarse hasta el último valor de `i`. Tal vez para números pequeños no tenga importancia. Pero con números muy grandes si que hay diferencia. Trata de descubrir si `2147483641` es primo, una vez usando el `&& primo` y luego sin él. Y verás la diferencia. Saludos

Comment: Vale ya entendí la aplicación, muchas gracias a todos por vuestras respuestas. Y gracias @alo Malbarez porque no se me había ocurrido visualizarlo de esa manera y me ayudó a verlo más claro.

Answer (score 0):

como va todo?
Según entiendo tu algoritmo sale del ciclo cuando encuentra que el número no es primo, para eso es esa parte del código && primo. Luego dices que si le quitas esa parte aún sigue funcionando, y por supuesto que debería hacerlo y te explico porqué.
Al principio defines la variable

```
boolean primo=true;
```

la cual en el transcurso del ciclo se convierte en false si encuentra un número el cual su residuo es 0.

```
if(numero%i==0)primo=false;
```

Por otro lado en ningún momento del ciclo esta variable la devuelves a true si encuentra un número el cual tiene un residuo diferente de 0, por lo cual una vez que encuentre que el numero es primo, no importa lo que pase, la variable va a seguir siendo false puesto que no la devuelves.

Para el caso en el que nombras:

1. el residuo de 8%2 = 0 entonces la variable primo se vuelve false
2. el ciclo sigue corriendo hasta 8%7 = 1 el cual tiene un residuo diferente de cero, pero previamente la variable primo ya se ha cambiado a false, y puesto que en ningún momento la vuelves true ella sigue siendo false.

Cambia tu if

```
if(numero%i==0)primo=false;
```

por este if para que lo compruebes

```
primo= (numero%i==0) ? false : true;
```

Saludos